# Point an URL to a local html-page via hosts file

Tags: mac, osx-lion, facebook, hosts-file

I want to surprise myself with a picture of an evil looking monkey every time I access Facebook by habit or rather by addiction.

**Therefore I added the following lines to /private/etc/hosts:**

```
# Block Facebook
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1 fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1 www.static.ak.connect.facebook.com
```

*The actual question is:* Does someone know a good way of letting it point to a local file e.g. in the OS X native „Website“-Folder. I *don't* want to run an apache all the time. I'd truly appreciate your help.

Comment: You could upload a picture to Photobucket and have it forward to those... I think that would be a lot easier... For instance have it point to a page like [this](http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_WQssiumLg8DP31L1R8ipS7WHTqXNLn15Hl43MdikzyjgwGCj_Q)

Comment: I forgot that you can't direct it to a specific URL, only IP addresses. @akub.gieryluk's answer is the only way I know of other than having some type of web server application installed on your server...

Answer (score 2):

[LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/leechblock/) is definitely the thing for you, if you're using Firefox. You can redirect any set of URLs (e.g. facebook.com/*) to a given URL.

Regarding hosts file, all you can is to do a redirect to a given IP (unless you use some extra application that will add more functions).